# Using jobs in laravel 5 in a shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, jobs, shared-hosting

I am using jobs in **laravel 5** and it works perfectly in localhost using the command, when I thought about using a shared hosting where there is no commands, I changed the code and I added commands to it and it still works in localhost using this function in *Kernel.php*

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:listen --timeout=0')->everyMinute();
}
```

But when it comes to a shared hosting I receive this error (*in a log file that I am using*) when launching the job

```
[2016-10-18 08:15:22] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 0' in /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/AbstractPipes.php:140
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/AbstractPipes.php(140): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/devaga/pu...', 140, Array)
#1 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/UnixPipes.php(98): Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\AbstractPipes->write()
#2 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(1320): Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\UnixPipes->readAndWrite(false, true)
#3 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(1240): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->readPipes(false, true)
#4 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(305): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->updateStatus(false)
#5 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(201): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->start(NULL)
#6 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(171): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run()
#7 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(153): Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event->runCommandInForeground(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#8 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(61): Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event->run(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand->fire()
#10 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#12 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))
#13 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))
#14 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(794): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))
#15 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(186): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))
#16 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))
#17 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(64): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))
#18 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\Console\Application->call('schedule:run', Array)
#19 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(217): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->call('schedule:run')
#20 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/app/Http/routes.php(33): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array)
#21 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/app/Http/routes.php(33): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('schedule:run')
#22 [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
#23 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(158): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#24 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(137): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runCallable(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#36 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#41 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#46 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#51 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#56 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#62 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#63 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#64 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#65 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#67 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#68 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#69 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#70 /home/devaga/public_html/HashtagApp/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#71 {main}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have more error information? A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: I added the stack trace (sorry I am not familiar with text edition in stackoverflow)